# zsh: permission denied, but I have all the permissions I need

Tags: terminal, zsh, file-permissions

I try to store a file in a variable using
'export FILE=PATH'
but when I try to print out the file like so:
'$FILE'
I get the error message:
'zsh: permission denied: PATH'
I already checked, if the file is restricted and created my own file and copy pasted the text in the new file and tried again, but it doesn't work.
What can I do?

Comment: Does `PATH` has executabl rights? `$FILE` does not **print** the file, it is supposed to **run** it. To **output** the file to the terminal, you would use something like `cat $FILE` or `less $FILE`, and to print it, `lpr $FILE`.

Comment: Thanks I thought to use this command u need just write and read rights

Comment: If you no longer need an answer to your question, then please close it.